# How to call onMenuItemSelected when showing progressdialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm new in android world.  I'm using `ProgressDialog` when i synchronizing data. In my view has a top menu. If I call mProgressDialog.show() it locks full screen, but **i want to use MenuItems at that moment**. I've tried to change position of `ProgressDialog`, however useless, also i've read from [android developers' forum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setIndeterminateDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) about onMenuItemSelected. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
private ProgressDialog mDialog ;

in Oncreate
mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyClass.this);
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

When it need to show i'm calling `mDialog.show();`. That's all.

Comment: Please provide extra info about the layout used , are you using actionbar or not. The code for creating ProgressDialog and the xml of the screen

Comment: use progressbar view rather progressdialog it will not block the screen

Comment: How to set text to progressbar? ;)